# STDIN from bash to perl script

Tags: perl, bash

i have a perl script(myscript.pl)

```
use strict;
use IO::Handle;

open OUTPUT, '>', "output.txt" or die $!;

STDOUT->fdopen( \*OUTPUT, 'w' ) or die $!;

while (<STDIN>){
print $_;
}
```

i can paste into output.txt what i write on commandline

also

I have a bash script:

```
cat >in.$$ 

cat in.$$> /tmp/msg
```

i can paste what i have in in.$$ into /tmp/msg

i need to run perl script with stdin that come from bash script.

is it possible and how?

i tried , even though i know it is too silly

```
cat in.$$> ./myscript.pl
in.$$> ./myscript.pl
in.$$> perl myscript.pl
```

Comment: I probably have misunderstood it, but, how about `./myscript.pl in.$$`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify the contents of a file as standard input to a bash command, use `<`

```
./myscript.pl < in.$$
```

To use the output of one command as the input to another command, use '|' (the 'pipe' character, as if you were sending bits from one process to another through a pipe)

```
cat in.$$ | ./myscript.pl
echo foo | ./myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 5):

In your Perl script, use the *diamond operator* (aka the *null file handle*):

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of `sed` and `awk`, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames.

Here's an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# cat command emulator

while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    say $line;
}
```

The `<>` will take each file listed on the command line, open them sequentially, and then read each line, **or** pull lines in from STDIN.

You can also do this:

```
while ( my $line = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp $line;
    say $line;
}
```

Which will read in lines from STDIN, but won't read files from the command line.